# 2 Wire Heating Unit. Upgrading Thermostat to a Smart tsat

Tags: thermostat, heater

I could really use some help here. Recently, my old Honeywell thermostat (2-wire) gave up on me, so I saw it as an opportunity to upgrade to a smart thermostat.

After examining my control board, I notice there isn't a C wire terminal.
This can possibly cause some issues with a new thermostat.

What's the best way to overcome this / adding a c-wire. How can a relay be connected in between the thermostat and the control board to help? I could go an easy way and purchase an AC-AC adapter, but there isn't a nearby power outlet so I'm not so keen in having to run a wire between the walls to a power outlet and hoping I could do everything from where the heater unit is located.

I'm eagerly looking forward to your support and suggestions!

Thanks[image]

Comment: this is for heating only (furnace), no cooling, look in the heat exchanger cabinet (with big fan). Do you even have Cooling, the outdoor unit

Comment: Do you have a third wire between the furnace and the thermostat location? If so this will be relatively simple. If not, a smart thermostat might still work, since these wires can provide a little bit of power.

Comment: Can you post photos of your furnace's wiring diagram please?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is a heater only unit. When I mentioned AC-AC adapter, I meant a 24VAC adapter to use as power+cwire. I'll get a picture of the wiring diagram tomorrow and post :)

Comment: Have you looked at any of the 50000 other questions we have here about how to add a C wire to a thermostat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old thermostat was battery operated and did not need C.

The smart thermostat needs 24 Volt for its operation and for the WiFi.

The 24 Volt supply comes as R+C wires from a 24 Volt transformer inside the control cabinet.

The picture you are showing is to control the Heating only, not Cooling. Look for another cabinet inside your home for another control board, where the huge heat exchanger coil and Fan is.

Look carefully at the cable coming out at the thermostat and how many wires it has. Maybe you have the C just not connected.

If not, you have two options.

Run a new cable or use Google Nest C generator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Appreciate your help. 
Yes, it's a heating only unit. The cooling in the house are separate split systems.

The heating thermostat was removed from the wall when we recently moved in (recently purchased). When I mentioned AC-AC adapter, I meant a 24VAC adapter to use as power/c-wire. 

Only 2 wires going to the thermostat location, (red and white). My multimeter is giving me a 27V reading. 

I'll take another look at the unit to see if there's another control board, but I think this was the only one where there is no C terminal.